# TypeScript Force Interface Attribute to One of Two Possible Types

Tags: typescript

I have an interface in my application that looks like the following:

```
interface Team {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  organization: Organization | number;
  responsibilities: Responsibility[] | number[];
  users?: User[] | number[];
}
```

The `organization` attribute can be an `Organization` or a `number` representing the ID of that `Organization`. I modeled it this way to share the interface between the front end and back end of my application.

The `organization` attribute is generally a number when the team is created, but then when displaying the team it comes back from the database as an instance of an `Organization`. This works, but it causes some issues where I have to add in a whole bunch of code to determine if the attribute is a number or an object.

I'm wondering if there's a way that in some places I can essentially say "this is a `Team` object where the `organization` will always be a number" or "this is a `Team` object where the `organization` will always be an instance of `Organization`.

I figure I could change the above interface to `TeamBase`, and then make a `Team` where `organization` is a number and another where it's an instance of `Organization`, but that becomes really complicated when there are multiple attributes on the object that have this same issue (i.e. the responsibilities and users on that same `Team` object).

Is what I'm explaining possible? Is there a better way to handle what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to set the organization type:

```
interface Team<TOrganization extends Organization | number> {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  organization: TOrganization;
  responsibilities: Responsibility[] | number[];
  users?: User[] | number[];
}
```

Then it is a matter of using the `Team` type as such: `Team<Organization>` or `Team<number>`.

If the interface is too long, there are multiple ways to do it. The most nuclear way (and also the least readable) could be:

```
type OrgOrNum = Organization | number;
interface Team<T extends OrgOrNum> {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  organization: T;
  responsibilities: Responsibility[] | number[];
  users?: User[] | number[];
}
```

Comment: I thought of this right after posting the question. I have one more question. Is there a way to store `TOrganization extends Organization | number` into a type/interface/value that can be used inside the brackets so that the generic declaration for the interface is a little cleaner?

Comment: You can store the union type as `type OrgOrNum = Organization | number` and then use `TOrganization extends OrgOrNum`, or you can shorten the generic to any arbitrary string, e.g. `T extends OrgOrNum`. It's a matter of trading off readability for brevity.